# How to Create a Smooth Slide Toggle with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, slidetoggle

Can we create a Smooth SlideToggle with ReactJS like this
`https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp`
Also please refer:
`http://jsfiddle.net/rFn5v/3/`
I have seen too many tutorials and every one is using states to do the slide toggle function and it is not smooth. Anyone who can help me to give a right answer on it will be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try using Collapse from React-Bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/

Comment: @Josal Thank You for your answer. Do you have any other reference without Bootstrap. Because I am searching for a solution which does'nt depend any third party librareis like Bootstrap and jQuery. If I can do it with core Vanilla JS that will be appreciated. Thank you for your time. It also helped me to get a new knowledge.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need, https://blog.openreplay.com/creating-a-collapsible-component-for-react/ it's using `transition: height ease 0.9s;` to get the smoothing effect.

Comment: @Josal Thank You!. Now I got a new knowledge. But how can we collapse others when open a certain panel.

Comment: Maybe we can have an array for managing the states like, https://codesandbox.io/embed/elegant-sunset-g0lj1y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark , to add a smooth effect refer to the before link

Answer (score 3):

You can use state to show and hide slides :
I have a list of slides in my App component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <SlideShow header="Header1" body="stuff 1" />
      <SlideShow header="Header2" body="stuff 2" />
      <SlideShow header="Header3" body="stuff 3" />
    </>
  );
}
```

and in each of the SlideShow : by changing the value of `show`, the slide opens and closes

```
function SlideShow({ header, body }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const showStyle = {
    height: "auto"
  };
  const hideStyle = {
    height: "0",
    paddingTop: "0",
    paddingBottom: "0"
  };
  return (
    <div className="header" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
      {header}
      <div id="first" className="content" style={show ? showStyle : hideStyle}>
        {body}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and css code :

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  background: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[you can see demo online](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-butterfly-uxcq73?file=/src/styles.css:0-257)

Comment: Thank You for your detailed reply and your time. Let me also know how we able to close other panel when open a certain panel. Also can we open a panel in default.

Comment: I Edit code , you can see it at https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-butterfly-uxcq73

Comment: did you notice, the smooth transition not works If we remove the padding. Actually I am looking for a smooth transition which will works in any kind of content regardless of any dependencies. Smooth transition of HTML Element with React and Vanilla JS is still a mystery. I referred a lot and could'nt find any good one. But jQuery has a well documentation about it https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp. But I wonder why VanillaJS and ReactJS is not coming with such a documentation. Anyway I got some new knowledge with your code. Thanks for That!

Comment: you can use `jquery` in `reactjs` project, but i dont recommend it. I'm sorry I couldn't provide a better answer

Comment: I got it why you not recommends jQuery. But the code example You given me new knowledge. Actually the person like you is really an asset in stackoverflow as you tried many options for me to achieve my requirement without hesitation. Thank You! You are Awesome!